# Does the new "native" FireFox for Android use NDK or the Dalvik engine?

Tags: android, firefox

Does FireFox use the standard Android API or the NDK to be "native"?

This page http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/08/firefox-for-android-goes-tablet-native/ says that

> "The new native interface for Android tablets means faster start-up
>   times and a much speedier Awesome Bar for searching, but it also means
>   the browser is a bit more Android-y and a bit less Firefox-y.

FireFox for all other platforms uses XUL / JavaScript and this means it is limited by the JavaScript engine - does native here mean it uses the "Dalvik" virtual machine or a lower level?

Comment: I'm fairly certain they just mean it's using native UI elements (TextViews and stuff) and not heavily customized custom views. I don't know that for sure, but that's what I got out of reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the user interface uses Dalvik.

The rendering engine uses the NDK, as it has all along.